# filesystem::exists() no funciona o hay algo que debo estar haciendo mal

Tags: c++, c++17

Quiero ver si existe un directorio que escribe el usuario, pero nunca los encuentra, lo cual hace que el siguiente codigo se convierta en un bucle infinito. Esta es la función en la que ocurre eso.

```
    string getRuta(void){
        string dir;
        short op = PreguntarCrearDirectorio();
    
        if(op == 0){
            do{
                //system("cls");
    
                std::cout << "Ingrese la ruta donde deseas organizar tus archivos: ";
                std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');  // Ignorar \n
                std::getline(std::cin, dir);
                std::replace(dir.begin(), dir.end(), '\\', '/');    // Por si el usuario ingresa la direccion con (/) en lugar de (\)
    
                std::cout << "RUTA: " << dir;
    
                if(!fs::exists(dir) || !fs::is_directory(dir))
                    std::cout << "El directorio no existe, o no es valido." << endl;
    
            } while(!fs::exists(dir) || !fs::is_directory(dir));
    
        } else if(op == 1){
            /* aun no desarrollado */
        } else{
            std::cout << "Error en eleccion de directorio." << endl;
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    
        std::cout << "RUTA: " << dir;
    
        return dir;
    }
```

No sé si es que estoy haciendo un mal uso de `exists` o de `is_directory`.
Como información adicional, la linea de codigo del replace la puse ya que cuando estaba probando el codigo sin esa linea seguía haciendo el bucle infinito igualmente, y documentandome sobre la libreria filesystem, en los ejemplos de uso no usaban esta barra (\) sino esta (/).

Aquí pongo un ejemplo de como se ve en consola.

```bash
Ingrese la ruta donde deseas organizar tus archivos: C:\Users\Pablo\Escritorio\Programming\Mi Proyecto
RUTA: C:\Users\Pablo\Escritorio\Programming\Mi Proyecto El directorio no existe, o no es valido.
Ingrese la ruta donde deseas organizar tus archivos:
```

Muchas gracias por su atención.

Answer (score 0):

prueba a quitar la linea

`std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n')`

Explicación:
Después de que se ejecute
`std::cout << "Ingrese la ruta donde deseas organizar tus archivos: "`
esa linea que te menciono está bloqueando el programa, porque le estás diciendo que ignore '\n', pero como no hay ningún '\n' pendiente, se bloquea, y cuando crees que le has dado el input a
`std::getline(std::cin, dir);`
se lo estás dando realmente a `std::cin.ignore()`

Acabo de probar a copiar y pegar tu código, simplemente comenté la línea
`std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n')`
y me inventé un PreguntarCrearDirectorio() que devuelve 0 directamente para probar la parte en la que tienes problemas.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;
using namespace std;

short PreguntarCrearDirectorio() { return 0; }

string getRuta(void) {
  string dir;
  short op = PreguntarCrearDirectorio();

  if (op == 0) {
    do {
      // system("cls");

      std::cout << "Ingrese la ruta donde deseas organizar tus archivos: ";
      // std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n'); //
      // Ignorar \n
      std::getline(std::cin, dir);
      std::replace(dir.begin(), dir.end(), '\\',
                   '/'); // Por si el usuario ingresa la direccion con (/) en
                         // lugar de (\)

      if (!fs::exists(dir) || !fs::is_directory(dir))
        std::cout << "El directorio no existe, o no es valido." << endl;

    } while (!fs::exists(dir) || !fs::is_directory(dir));

  } else if (op == 1) {
    /* aun no desarrollado */
  } else {
    std::cout << "Error en eleccion de directorio." << endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  std::cout << "RUTA: " << dir;

  return dir;
};

int main() {
  auto a = getRuta();
  std::cout << "ruta: " << a << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```